# How to parse a Json with a field containg several kind of objects

Tags: java, android, jackson

How to parse a Json with a field "data" which can contain several types of objets, or an object and a simple message (outside the object structure).

An Android app request information to its backend. In most cases, the response has the same structure and if the "data" field only contains one kind of object i can complete the process.

But if the "data" field contains several kinds of objects or one object with a external message, i can´t parse it.

Normal Response structure (I can parse these cases):

```
{
    "success": true,
    "code": "OK",
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "_type": "auth",
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlzcyI6Im9mZnRpbWUiLCJzdWIiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXIifQ==.eyJyb2xlIjpbImFwcCJdLCgfgdfgJhcgdfgdfAiOiJPRkZUSU1FIEFuZHJvaWQiLCJvd25lcdsgsghhjghkukI6Ik9zY2FyIn0=.7PiMEmX8M3ABs7P8KymuXvBpTL1gdgdfLRajFbwxP5IBARM=",
        "refresh": null,
        "logout": null
    }
}
```

Response with an object "user" and a message (i have problems parsing it):

```
{
    "success": true,
    "code": "USER_ALREADY_EXISTS",
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "_type": "user",
            "id": 32,
            "name": "Pascual22",
            "email": "pascual22@juanedc.com",
            "picture": null
        },
        "message": "This email is already registered, you will receive an email with the reset password instructions"
    }
}
```

Response with several kinds of objects (i have problems parsing it):

```
{
    "success": true,
    "code": "OK",
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "auth": {
            "_type": "auth",
            "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlzcyI6Im9mZnRpbWUiLCJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTYwNTk2MzUwfQ==.eyJyb2xlIjpbImFwcCIsInVzZXIiXSwib3duZXIiOjI2LCJkZXZpY2UiOiI5In0=.JxbidqCnZNCt8eyRUbLE8HEJKeWgwFejz/9rMJPoKS0=",
            "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlzcyI6Im9mZnRpbWUiLCJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTYwNzY5MTUwfQ==.eyJyb2xlIjpbImFwcCIsInVzZXIiLCJyZWZyZXNoIl0sIm93bmVyIjoyNiwiZGV2aWNlIjoiOSIsInJlZnJlc2giOiJleUowZVhBaU9pSktWMVFpTENKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJbWx6Y3lJNkltOW1ablJwYldVaUxDSnpkV0lpT2lKMWMyVnlJaXdpWlhod0lqb3hOVFl3TlRrMk16VXdmUT09LmV5SnliMnhsSWpwYkltRndjQ0lzSW5WelpYSWlYU3dpYjNkdVpYSWlPakkyTENKa1pYWnBZMlVpT2lJNUluMD0uSnhiaWRxQ25aTkN0OGV5UlViTEU4SEVKS2VXZ3dGZWp6XC85ck1KUG9LUzA9In0=.JBTIyHAtVS8PgH7LzUzL3TTg8yoe7vVMBH6eauPgc7o=",
            "logout": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImlzcyI6Im9mZnRpbWUiLCJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTYwNTk2MzUwfQ==.eyJyb2xlIjpbImFwcCIsInVzZXIiLCJsb2dvdXQiXSwib3duZXIiOjI2LCJkZXZpY2UiOiI5IiwibG9nb3V0IjoiZXlKMGVYQWlPaUpLVjFRaUxDSmhiR2NpT2lKSVV6STFOaUlzSW1semN5STZJbTltWm5ScGJXVWlMQ0p6ZFdJaU9pSjFjMlZ5SWl3aVpYaHdJam94TlRZd05UazJNelV3ZlE9PS5leUp5YjJ4bElqcGJJbUZ3Y0NJc0luVnpaWElpWFN3aWIzZHVaWElpT2pJMkxDSmtaWFpwWTJVaU9pSTVJbjA9Lkp4YmlkcUNuWk5DdDhleVJVYkxFOEhFSktlV2d3RmVqelwvOXJNSlBvS1MwPSJ9.syuKoi8XiHp/me/AJAydyXfRbXa63KVWqPSKS7ySGQc="
        },
        "user": {
            "_type": "user",
            "id": 26,
            "name": "Sin Foto 2",
            "email": "sf2@yopmail.com",
            "picture": null
        },
        "device": {
            "_type": "device",
            "id": "9",
            "category": "mobile",
            "manufacturer": "Xiaomi",
            "model": "Mi A1",
            "os": "android",
            "os_version": "9",
            "sim_support": true,
            "name": null,
            "added": "2019-06-10 10:59:10"
        }
    }
}
```

My class response:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty("success")
    private String success;
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty("error")
    private String error;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Object data;

    public String getSuccess() {return success;}

    public void setSuccess(String success) {this.success = success;}

    public String getCode() {return code;}

    public void setCode(String code) {this.code = code;}

    public String getError() {return error;}

    public void setError(String error) {this.error = error;}

    public Object getData() {return data;}

    public void setData(Object data) {this.data = data;}

}
```

Initial parsing process (from Json to Response Object, using spring for android framework, ):

```
responseApi = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Response.class);
```

Parsing Process of data field to Objects (Example with a user object in "data"):

```
try {
                        User user = mapper.convertValue(responseApi.getBody().getData(), User.class);
}
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried to make a Data class with a generic object and a message atributes, but, it din´t work. I need to parse the response in all cases, how can i achieve it? Some suggestions about the class structure in order to make a correct automatic parsing process?

Comment: Follow some step : Convert Json response to respective model from [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). now `ReponseClass user = mapper.convertValue(responseApi.getBody().getData(), ReponseClass .class);`

Comment: Nice tool, very useful. But there's an additional problem, "data" can contain any kind of object, not only Users, is there a way to make it generic, in order to can parse any kind of object?

Comment: ok so make it object, it will work!